# Does the requirement for how to override a virtual function have changed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++23

Please see this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/nTf431We1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class B{
public:
    virtual void fun() &{  //#1
        std::cout<<"base\n";
    }
};
class A:public B{
public:
  void fun(){  //#2
      std::cout<<"override\n";
  }
};
int main(){
   A  a;
   B* ptr = &a;
   ptr->fun();
}
```

GCC prints `base` while Clang prompts an error diagnosis. In the current draft, the relevant rule is defined like that:
[[class.virtual#2]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#2)

> If a virtual member function F is declared in a class B, and, in a class D derived (directly or indirectly) from B, a declaration of **a member function G corresponds ([basic.scope.scope]) to a declaration of F**, ignoring trailing requires-clauses, **then G overrides F**.

Simultaneously, the rule for defining two declarations who correspond is defined like that:
[[basic.scope#scope-3]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-3)

> Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless
>
> > - [...]
> > - each declares a function or function template, except when
> >
> > > - both declare functions with the same parameter-type-list, equivalent ([temp.over.link]) trailing requires-clauses (if any, except as specified in [temp.friend]), and, if both are non-static members, the same cv-qualifiers (if any) and ref-qualifier (**if both have one**), or

In this example, `#1` and `#2` have the same parameter-type-list, `#1` has one ref-qualifier while `#2` does not have, hence the latter restriction could be ignored, hence, for these two declarations, we could say they correspond. Hence, `#2` overrides `#1` that is declared as a virtual function. Hence, we could say both GCC and Clang have the wrong result if we obey the current draft.

However, in the c++20 standard, the restriction for how to determine a declaration declared in the derived class overrides the virtual function declared in the base class is:
[[class.virtual#2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.virtual#2)

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with **the same name, parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same)** as Base​::​vf is declared, then Derived​::​vf overrides Base​::​vf.

It's obvious that the current rule has changed its original meaning. Is it a defect in the new rule? Or, it's just the artificial design to make the requirement be changed?

Comment: I imagine the new wording is just a clarification to the original wording, the implementation of gcc and clang doesn't seem to have changed: https://godbolt.org/z/rerbrKqoj

Comment: @AlanBirtles The new wording is not just a clarification to the original wording. It has changed the original meaning. It has permitted that the overriding function has no req-qualifier while the overridden function has one. BTW, the latest compilers may obey the c++20 standard.

Comment: I don’t think Clang’s behavior is correct for either wording, but I don’t know what would be best here.  Between the meaning change and the implementation divergence, this seems like a good core language issue to file; why not do that instead of asking here?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, Clang is totally wrong in either version. Thanks for you to confirm of this issue. I have issued it to the <<draft>> on Github, simultaneously, filed it to the core language issue.

Comment: The problem, as I understand it, is that "correspond" is used in the rules for both overloading and overriding.  If we interpret it to mean "they shouldn't overload", then the override is legal; and vice versa.  So this isn't just a different interpretation, but a change in meaning.

Comment: What error, if any, do you get if you change `A::fun` to include the `override` keyword (`void fun() override`)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The keyword `override` is not necessary in this example. Even add the keyword would make GCC report diagnosis(has the same behavior with Clang), this is still a core language issue in the current draft.